# Optimisation - cone question

Tags: calculus

[image]

I have $V=81\pi=\dfrac{1}{3}\pi r^2h$

but I don't have the length of the cone, so how can I use $C.S.A=\pi rl$?

Not sure how to do this question, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, but which part are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  The slant height of the cone is $$l = \sqrt{r^2 + h^2}$$  You can solve the volume equation for $h$ in terms of $r$ to eliminate $h$ from your equations.

Comment: I got something like: $s=\pi r\sqrt{\dfrac{r^4+243^2}{r^2}}$. I think that's right so far, but I don't really understand manipulating algebra in square root fractions, so could you explain this bit please?